# Apply Side input to BigQueryIO.read operation in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is there a way to apply a side input to a BigQueryIO.read() operation in Apache Beam.

Say for example I have a value in a PCollection that I want to use in a query to fetch data from a BigQuery table. Is this possible using side input? Or should something else be used in such a case?

I used NestedValueProvider in a similar case but I guess we can use that only when a certain value depends on my runtime value. Or can I use the same thing here? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The code that I tried:

```
Bigquery bigQueryClient = start_pipeline.newBigQueryClient(options.as(BigQueryOptions.class)).build();
    Tabledata tableRequest = bigQueryClient.tabledata();

PCollection<TableRow> existingData = readData.apply("Read existing data",ParDo.of(new DoFn<String,TableRow>(){
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws IOException
    {
        List<TableRow> list = c.sideInput(bqDataView);
        String tableName = list.get(0).get("table").toString();
        TableDataList table = tableRequest.list("projectID","DatasetID",tableName).execute();

        for(TableRow row:table.getRows())
        {
            c.output(row);
        }
    }
    }).withSideInputs(bqDataView));
```

The error that I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to serialize BeamTest.StarterPipeline$1@86b455
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:53)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.clone(SerializableUtils.java:90)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo$SingleOutput.<init>(ParDo.java:569)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo.of(ParDo.java:434)
    at BeamTest.StarterPipeline.main(StarterPipeline.java:158)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery$Tabledata
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:49)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Beam model does not currently support this kind of data-dependent operation very well.

A way of doing it is to code your own `DoFn` that receives the side input and connects directly to BQ. Unfortunately, this would not give you any parallelism, as the `DoFn` would run completely on the same thread.

Once Splittable `DoFn`s are supported in Beam, this will be a different story.

---

In the current state of the world, you would need to use the [BQ client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) to add code that would query BQ as if you were not in a Beam pipeline.

Given the code in your question, a rough idea on how to implement this is the following:

```
class ReadDataDoFn extends DoFn<String,TableRow>(){
    private Tabledata tableRequest;

    private Bigquery bigQueryClient;

    private Bigquery createBigQueryClientWithinDoFn() {
        // I'm not sure how you'd implement this, but you had the right idea
    }

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        bigQueryClient = createBigQueryClientWithinDoFn(); 
        tableRequest = bigQueryClient.tabledata();
    }
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws IOException
    {
        List<TableRow> list = c.sideInput(bqDataView);
        String tableName = list.get(0).get("table").toString();
        TableDataList table = tableRequest.list("projectID","DatasetID",tableName).execute();

        for(TableRow row:table.getRows())
        {
            c.output(row);
        }
    }
}

PCollection<TableRow> existingData = readData.apply("Read existing data",ParDo.of(new ReadDataDoFn()));
```

Comment: Okay @pablo. Can you please provide an example of connecting a DoFn to BigQuery. It will really be helpful.

Comment: What I mean with my answer is you would need to use the BQ client library (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) to add code that would query BQ as if you were not in a Beam pipeline. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah...I'll give it a try. Thanks @pablo

Comment: I've updated the post with a code that I tried. But I get an error saying "unable to serialize". Is this approach fine?

Comment: You got the right idea, but you need to do the connection to bigquery from within a worker, not at pipeline creation. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Also, note that this is a really awkward form of use of Beam, but it's currently the only way to provide the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @pablo...I used the BigQuery Client Libraries from the link that you gave and I was able to do that...thanks :)
I was getting the same error with the code that I had provided so went with BQ Client Library...
Can you provide that comment as an answer...I'll mark it as correct!!

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out. I've added the information in the comment to my answer.