# Pcollection for multiple Tables

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have two bigquery tables.

Table A

```
c_id    count_c_id  p_id
```

Table B

```
id   c_name   p_type  c_id
```

Based on columns in Table A, I need to find details from Table B using DF pipelines.

```
PCollection<TableRow> tableRowBQ = pipeline.apply(BigQueryIO.Read
.named("Read").fromQuery("select c_id,count_c_id,p_id from TableA"));
```

My requirement is based on c_id return by this query I should be able to get c_name from TableB using pcollection. I am not able to find any example of pcollection for iterating field from one table and fetch data from another table using that field.

Example shared by Google Team as a reference.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowSDK-examples/blob/master-1.x/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/cookbook/JoinExamples.java.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Cloud DataFlow documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/group-by-key), I think you have two approaches to complete this kind of **JOIN** task. Depending on how many unique `c_id`s you have, I would choose one of the two options below.

- if you don't have many `c_id`s, I would treat the result from your `SELECT` query as a side input, and use that as filter to pass into a lookup into Table B;

Here is a code snippet to consume BigQueryIO query result as side input: [Apply Side input to BigQueryIO.read operation in Apache Beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419994/apply-side-input-to-bigqueryio-read-operation-in-apache-beam).

- Otherwise, you can use `CoGroupByKey`. For example,

```
Table A:
c_id -> count_c_id, p_id

Table B
c_id -> c_name
```

Since both tables can be seen as a shared key to some different values, you can **CoGroup** them into

```
c_id -> ([count_c_id, p_id], [c_name]]
```

then you can do whatever you want on this "grouped" new PCollection.

Comment: Can you tell me logic for how can I write sideinput?

Comment: yay, here is a code snippet to consume BigQueryIO query result as side input: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419994/apply-side-input-to-bigqueryio-read-operation-in-apache-beam