# Apache Beam IOElasticsearchIO.read() method (Java), which expects a PBegin input and a means to handle a collection of queries

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, beam

I'm running into an issue using the `ElasticsearchIO.read()` to handle more than one instance of a query. My queries are being dynamically built as a `PCollection` based on an incoming group of values.  I'm trying to see how to load the `.withQuery()` parameter which could provide this capability or any approach that provides flexibility.

The issue is that `ElasticsearchIO.read()` method expects a `PBegin` input to start a pipeline, but it seems like I need access outside of a pipeline context somehow. PBegin represents the beginning of a pipeline, and it's required to create a pipeline that can read data from Elasticsearch using `IOElasticsearchIO.read()`.

Can I wrap the `ElasticsearchIO.read()` call in a Create transform that creates a PCollection with a single element (e.g., PBegin) to simulate the beginning of a pipeline or something similar?

Here is my naive attempt without accepting the reality of `PBegin`:

```java
   PCollection<String> queries = ... // a PCollection of Elasticsearch queries
    
    PCollection<String> queryResults = queries.apply(
        ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                String query = c.element();
                PCollection<String> results = c.pipeline()
                    .apply(ElasticsearchIO.read()
                        .withConnectionConfiguration(
                            ElasticsearchIO.ConnectionConfiguration.create(hosts, indexName))
                        .withQuery(query));
                c.output(results);
            }
        })
    .apply(Flatten.pCollections()));
```

In general I'm wondering for any of IO-related classes proved by Beam that conforms to PBegin input -- if there is a means to introduce a collection.  Here is one approach that might be promising:

```java
// Define a ValueProvider for a List<String>
ValueProvider<List<String>> myListProvider = ValueProvider.StaticValueProvider.of(myList);

// Use the ValueProvider to create a PCollection of Strings
PCollection<String> pcoll = pipeline.apply(Create.ofProvider(myListProvider, ListCoder.of()));
```

Comment: Please can you share a code snippet ?

Comment: Sorry please can you move the code snippet in your question instead of a comment, for more readability ?

Comment: Should I include something else?  I'm a newbie so I'm not sure if this is acceptable or if more information is needed.

Comment: No it's perfect thanks. Have you many queries to launch ?

Comment: It depends on the size of the cohort I'm processing.  Rather than being a batch process this is actually part of a streaming process that reads from a PubSubIO subscription.  Based on a predetermined batch size and time window the collaboration of SearchHits is provided.

Comment: I was looking at the "Related questions" below, specifically, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419994/apply-side-input-to-bigqueryio-read-operation-in-apache-beam?rq=2  It is about 5 years old and mentions the Splittable DoFns becoming available in the future.   I'm wondering if this approach has potential.

Comment: I'll guess this question isn't suitable for this forum.  I'll try elsewhere. Thanks